# For Loop in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Don't understand this simple code:

```
def main():
  print ("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
  x = float(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
  for r in range(1,10):
    x = 3.9*x*(1 - x)
    print(x)
```

According to my understanding it should print out 10 identical numbers.
But it gives me 10 different. I thought that range (1,10) only means that it
iterates trough code 10 times.

Comment: It does loop (not 10) **9** times, but you reassign x to the new value.

Comment: range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers
    
    Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
    range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`r` changes from 1 to 9. `x` changes from `"old x"` to `"new x" = 3.9*(old x)*(1 - (old x))` 9 times, starting from the input value.

Comment: Now i feel like donkey! But I guess this is the path of learning. I managed somehow to ignore fact that X changes from initial imput. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

`range(a,b)` returns a tmp list`[a, a+1, ..., b-2, b-1]`, there's no `b`.